# Writing equations for parabolas

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I wanted to know how to write an equation of a parabola with a focus and a directrix given.

Ex: focus $(2,-2)$, directrix $x=-5$

Ex: focus $(-3,4)$, directrix $y=9$

I don't know how to write an equation when it gives a directrix of $x$ or $y$. I've looked on Google and YouTube and they are very confusing at explaining

Answer (score 0):

Parabola is defined as the *locus of points P having equal distance from the focus F and the directrix d.*

$$PF=PH$$
Where *H* is the projection of *P* on *d*.

Let $P(x,y)$ be any point of the plane. It belongs to the parabola having focus $F(-3,4)$ and directrix $d:\;y=9$ if it satisfies the previous condition, that is
$$\sqrt{(x-(-3))^2 + (y-4)^2}=\left|y-9\right|$$
Square both sides
$$(x + 3)^2 + (y - 4)^2 = (y - 9)^2$$
Expand, simplify and rearrange:
$$y = - \frac{x^2}{10} - \frac{3}{5}\,x + \frac{28}{5}$$
Memorize a formula is useless, IMO.

Hope this helps...